# Selenium with Headless Chrome (2016) on TravisCI

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, travis-ci

[Chrome has now a native headless mode](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md). I'd like to set this up to run Selenium tests on TravisCI, without Xvfb.

- Are there easy to install Headless Chrome binaries on TravisCI, as most of recipes only start with compiling Headless Chrome from source
- Does Selenium need any specific hints when used with Headless Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Travis offers the [usage of the chrome add-on](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/#Using-the-Chrome-addon-in-the-headless-mode). If you want to run your build on Linux(trusty) all you have to do is specify chrome in your travis-file and start the browser in headless-mode before you start testing.

```
dist: trusty
addons:
  chrome: stable
before_install:
  - # start your web application and listen on `localhost`
  - google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://localhost &
```